# How restore the panel in the design view of Jframe in netbeans java?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a problem in the design view of Jframe in netbeans java.I unchecked the visible property of the panel in the Jframe and the panel is not seen the design view.I want to get the panel back into the frame in the design view itself .Please help me solve this.

Comment: Can you post some code? We can't guess.

Comment: What's your netbeans version? i cant see visible proprerty on my version, for JPanel component.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating another project where panel is visible and comparing the code between the two projects. 
Try to be creative and figure out these kinds of problems on your own, you will benefit more than you can now imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `opaque property` of jpanel,you might make it invisible.If the issue is that;
 In design view you can see `Navigator Panel`  bottom left side.You can see all of components you have created in here.For solving the issue

```
Navigator Panel->find your jPanel ->Right Click->Properties Window->Check Opaque Property
```